# Catalog Price Rule Not applying for all products

Tags: product, price, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, catalog-rules

We are creating a catalog price rule mapping to a particular category. There are three different problems.

1. The rule is applied only to certain products in the category and not the other products.
2. The rule stopped working on a certain day in between the given time gap.
3. The rule did not get reflected when the starting date was same as the rule creation date, whereas once the rule starting date was changed to one day prior to the rule creation date, the rule got reflected in the front end.

Any help on this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1)Create an attribute and using "Update attributes" option select all those products to one attribute value and apply catalog price rule to that attribute.  This is not answer to your first point. but it is the other way for applying rules for the products.

2)check cron job is working or not . If not working, than catalog price rules will disappear after some time. click on "Apply catalog price rules" again when it disappear and reindex .

3)Dont select date when creating catalog price rules. leave the "from and to date" to blank. Check even your server time and magento site time is same.